# Iterating two variables over a single list

Tags: python, loops, graph-algorithm

I am trying to write a program which iterates i,j and k,and finds the minimum value given a certain formula (vik + vkj - vij), where v is a 2d list of distances between points, k is a new point two be inserted into the new array and i,j are existing values in the new array.
Sorry if this explanation is a little confusing...

My code is this:

```
values = [[0,2],[3,3],[4,5],[2,1],[7,1]]
points = [0,1,2,3,4]
new = [2,4]

for k in points: #k is the point that will be inserted
    minVal = 1000000000000000 #set to any arbitrarily high value, that will be larger than any other distance
    for i,j in new: 
        nextVal = values[i][k] + values[k][j] - values[i][j] # finds value which minimises vik + vkj - vij
        if nextVal < minVal:
            minVal = nextVal
            idx = i #saves index of i,j that gave minimal value, so that k can be inserted between these
            jdx = j
    new.insert(idx + 1, k) #insert after idx or before jdx
```

Anyway the probem is I get:

```
for i,j in new: 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I read somewhere that this is because objects of type int can't be iterated, but I don't get how else to solve this.

How can I have two separate values iterate through a list of ints, while making sure I remember which two values of i,j gave the minimum value, so I can then add k in between them?

Comment: look into `enumerate()`

Comment: `for i, j in new` is for values of `new` like `[(2,4)]`, where `i==2` and j==4` on the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the description of what you're aiming to do, but I can solve this error for you. It's in the line of code:

```
for i,j in new:
```

You have defined new as the list [2,4]. So when you do for i,j in [2,4], Python automatically unpacks the list and now you have for i,j in 2,4, which of course can't be iterated. It is forbidden to do something like:

```
for i in 2:
```